# Extract UTC time and convert it to Unix time format

Tags: android, datetime, time, formatting, utc

I have tow issues :

1- get UTC time from Android device
2- Convert it to UNIX time format ( millseconds )

I appreciated any feedback can help

Comment: java 101 : System.currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); // this gets you current time as a Date
long milis = now.getTime(); // this gets you current time in UNIX format
```